# Delphi 2010 - How to delete a line in a memo based into deleted item of a listbox?

Tags: delphi

I have a two objects in a form: 1 listbox and 1 memo. I'm trying to delete a item in the listbox1 and the same line index in the memo using this code:

```
  procedure TForm1.ListBox1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
      Shift: TShiftState);
    var i:integer; //seting a variable
    begin
    if key=vk_delete then //if key = a delete
    begin
    for i:=0  to listbox1.items.count -1   
    begin

  listbox1.DeleteSelected; //delete the selected line of the listbox
  memo2.Lines.Delete(i);   //delete the line based on the listbox selected item
    end;
    end;
        end;
```

But it only work if i add one line to listbox. If i add two lines in the listbox and try to delete a item 2, the memo1 delete the line 1; and if i add more items into listbox and try delete, various lines are deleted in the memo1. I think this is due to the fact that the memo begins index in 0 and listbox begins in 1.. However I can not solve this problem. Can anyone help me delete in both objects, only the row that I select in the object listbox?

Comment: No, all indices are zero-based.

Comment: -1 for horribly formatted code which does not even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simply that you are deleting multiple lines from the memo. That's because, for some reason, you coded a loop which deleted in each and every iteration of the loop. You don't want to do that. You only want to delete a single line.

You need to use code along these lines:

```
var
  Index: Integer;
....
Assert(ListBox1.Items.Count=Memo2.Lines.Count);
Index := ListBox1.ItemIndex;
if Index<>-1 then 
begin
  ListBox1.Items.Delete(Index);
  Memo2.Lines.Delete(Index);
end;
```

I have replaced your code which looped over the list box items and deleted multiple items from the list box, and multiple rows from the memo. Instead I obtain the index of the selected item in the list box, and make a single deletion from the list box and remove a single line from the memo.

Comment: Thanks sir Heffernan, your code works perfectly, however for me I'm very beginner, it is somewhat difficult to understand him, anyway I say: thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code makes absolutely no sense. It doesn't even come close to doing what I believe you want to do, which is this:

Create a new VCL project. Add a `TListBox` and a `TMemo` control. Add the same lines to them in the IDE (e.g., `alpha`, `beta`, `gamma`, `delta`, and `epsilon`).

Then add the following event handler:

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = VK_DELETE) and (ListBox1.ItemIndex <> -1) then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Delete(ListBox1.ItemIndex);
    ListBox1.DeleteSelected;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks sir Rejbrand, your code also works fine and is a little more next from what I understand (really understand little). Thank you.